# Username and Password for sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, authentication, timeout, sqlplus

I have installed sqlplus (version 21.4.0.0.0) on a Linux system. During installation, no username or password was asked. I'm unable to start sqlplus due to the lack of username and password. I checked for any response file that I may have installed for silent installation but didn't find any. I tried entering my oracle account credential but after some wait, it shows a timeout error. Is there any default username or password? Image below.

[Timeout Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgRn8.jpg)

Comment: You're getting a connection error, not an authentication error. SQL\*Plus is a *client* - you need a database to connect to. Have you installed the Oracle server software and created a database; or have you been given connection information for an existing database?

Comment: I kinda followed this tutorial to install sqlplus and I have not installed anything else other than the things mentioned on this website
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-sqlplus-on-linux/

Comment: "The main purpose of SQLplus is to interact with the Oracle DB", it is not the database itself. So, you need to decide if you want/need a database running locally and natively on your current machine; or a database running in a virtual machine (possibly a pre-built one); or have an existing DB you're supposed to connect to; or can use an online resource like Live SQL or SQL Fiddle or db<>fiddle. It really depends what you are trying to do and why, and how much administration you want to do. This isn't really the place to ask about any of that though.